# Fatal error: Trait 'Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor' not found in generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php on line 7

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

My client site suddenly get down today.
I tried to running php/magento deploy:mode:set developer. The terminal showing the error:
Fatal error: Trait 'Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor' not found in public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php on line 7

No matter what command line I ran, I always get this error. Anyone can help! Thank you!

Comment: maybe the file `Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor` got corrupted. Check to see if it looks like it should. Compare it to the one in a clean install

Answer (score 0):

> **Please run the below command.**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:Deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

sudo chmod  777 -R  var/* pub/* generated/*
```

Acording to comment of @lancwl and @Marius♦ .

**Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor** got corrupted. Check to see if it looks like it should. Compare it to the one in a clean install.

**Interceptor.php** file missed in **vendor/magento/framework/Interception/** So we copied one to this folder and then it's working.

Comment: yes. I have already did that. And I also try to remove all the generated/*. But still facing the same issue. So annoying.

Comment: I updated the command. Please check it.

Comment: Thank for your help. We finally figured it now. Somehow, interceptor.php file missed  in vendor/magento/framework/Interception/  So we copied one to this folder and then it's working.

Comment: @lancwl Thanks. I updated the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the generated code: and Run the following command:**

```
rm -rf generated/*
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
```